# execute python script local to docker client - no volumes

Tags: python, django, docker

I can run a bash script *local* to my docker client (not local to the docker host or targeted container), without using volumes or copying the script to the container:

```
docker run debian bash -c "`cat script.sh`"
```

Q1 How do I do the equivalent on a django container? The following have not worked but my help demonstrate what Im asking for (the bash script printf the python script line with the expaned args):

```
docker run django shell < `cat script.py`
cat script.py | docker run django shell
```

Q2 How do I pass arguments to script.py passed to a dockerized managed.py? Again, examples of what does not work (for me):

```
./script.sh arg1 arg2 | docker run django shell
docker run django shell < echo "$(./script.sh arg1 arg2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is to use custom Dockerfile that uses COPY or ADD command to move whatever scripts you into the container.

As for passing arguments you can either use ENTRYPOINT command in your image, like the example below:

```
ENTRYPOINT django shell /home/script.sh
```

Then you can use `docker run arg1 arg2` to pass the arguments

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the question is specifically how to do it without copying or volumes, just like with the bash example. manage.py is the entrypoint but does not have a -c and shell does not take arguments. Its almost more of a python question than docker.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to pass the command line arguments to python:    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

eg: python script.py -param1

If the script is already available in the docker you can trigger it using Dockerfile(with passing parameters)

```
RUN /script.py -param1 <value>
```

Extra:
Having said that it is always difficult to change the Dockerfile if there are more parameters to be changed frequently.Hence a small shell script can be written as a wrapper to Dockerfile like this:

```
Dockerwrapper.sh

pass parameters to Dockerfile
dockerbuild --tag <name> .
```

-

```
Dockerfile 

 RUN python script.py -param1 $1
```

I -------------------------------------------

IF script is not present inside docker
You can copy the script inside and then delete it by using COPY,RUN command...
(Reason: Since docker is an isolated environment, running from outside is not possible (I GUESS..))

Hoped it answered ur question.
All the best

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pratik. A few things, the script is local to the docker client and not the docker host. I am after the equivalent of the bash example (docker run debian bash -c "`cat script.sh`") where script.sh is on my laptop and not copied in the Docker file or nor accessed via a host volume at run time.

Comment: Please use Exec commands to ssh the script to the docker host.
And for passing parameters please use Dockerfile instead of -c.